# Rock Paper Scissor Array application C#

Tags: c#

Let me start off with what i have so far. Here are my 3 classes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game rps = new Game();
        rps.printHeader();
        rps.gameStart();
    }
}





class GameDetails
{
    public string Name;
    public int game;

    public GameDetails()
    {
        Name = "unknown";
        game = 0;
    }
}




class Game
{
    string name;
    int numPlays;
    int game;
    GameDetails[] gameArray;



    public int NumGames
    {
        get
        {
            return numPlays;
        }
        set
        {
            numPlays = value;
        }
    }

    public void printHeader()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors");
        this.userSettings();
    }

    private void InitializeArrays()
    {
        gameArray = new GameDetails[game];
        for (int game = 0; game < numPlays; game++)
        {
            gameArray[game] = new GameDetails();
        }

    }

    public void userSettings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name: ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("How many games would you like to play?: ");
        Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numPlays);
        while (numPlays < 10 && numPlays % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nNumber is not odd try again.");
            Console.WriteLine("How many games would you like to play?: ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numPlays);
        }

    }


    public void gameStart()
    {

        for (game = 1; game <= numPlays; game++)

            Console.WriteLine("Please choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
        string userSelection = Console.ReadLine();

        Random r = new Random();
        int computerSelection = r.Next(4);


        if (computerSelection == 1)
        {
            if (userSelection == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
            }
            else if (userSelection == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Paper\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Game[{ 0}] is a tie", game);
            }
            else if (userSelection == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Scissors\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");
            }

        }

        else if (computerSelection == 2)
        {
            if (userSelection == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Paper\n");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], papaer beats rock", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Scissors\n");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], scissors beats paper", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], Rock beats scissors", game);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");
            }

        }


        else if (computerSelection == 3)
        {
            if (userSelection == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer chose scissors");
                Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}], rock beats scissors", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer chose rock");
                Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}],paper beats rock", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer chose paper");
                Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}], scissors beats paper!", game);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            //        int arrayIndex = game - 1;
            //        gameArray[arrayIndex].Result = game;
            //    }


            //    }

            //public override string ToString()
            //{


            //    string outputString = game + "\n";

            //    for (int game = 1; game < numPlays; game++)
            //    {
            //        int index = game - 1;
            //        outputString += "Game " + game + ":" + gameArray[index].Result + "\n";
            //    }

            //    return outputString;
            //}


        }
    }
}
```

I need this program to only run for the specified number of games, determine a winner of a best of (number of games chosen) series, and display the results of each game. I am not receiving any errors, but when i run the code, it asks for the name and how many games. After i choose how many games to play, it just displays "Please choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors" the same number of times that i have chosen for the amount of games. How can i make this correctly count the number of games, determine a winner, and display the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop `for (game = 1; game <= numPlays; game++)` is missing the braces around the game method. From how it appears

```
for (game = 1; game <= numPlays; game++)
     Console.WriteLine("Please choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
```

The part `Console.WriteLine(..)` will run as many times as the `numPlays` is set.

What you will want to do is wrap the entire method body in the for loop and that should run the game repeatadly for `numPlays`

```
public void gameStart()
{ 
    Random r = new Random();
    for (game = 1; game <= numPlays; game++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
        string userSelection = Console.ReadLine();


        int computerSelection = r.Next(4);


        if (computerSelection == 1)
        {
            if (userSelection == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
            }
            else if (userSelection == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Paper\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Game[{ 0}] is a tie", game);
            }
            else if (userSelection == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Scissors\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");
            }

        }

        else if (computerSelection == 2)
        {
            if (userSelection == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Paper\n");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], papaer beats rock", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Scissors\n");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], scissors beats paper", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], Rock beats scissors", game);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");
            }

        }


        else if (computerSelection == 3)
        {
            if (userSelection == "rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer chose scissors");
                Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}], rock beats scissors", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer chose rock");
                Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}],paper beats rock", game);

            }
            else if (userSelection == "scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The computer chose paper");
                Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}], scissors beats paper!", game);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            //        int arrayIndex = game - 1;
            //        gameArray[arrayIndex].Result = game;
            //    }


            //    }

            //public override string ToString()
            //{


            //    string outputString = game + "\n";

            //    for (int game = 1; game < numPlays; game++)
            //    {
            //        int index = game - 1;
            //        outputString += "Game " + game + ":" + gameArray[index].Result + "\n";
            //    }

            //    return outputString;
            //}


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, Random inside a for loop. Not very random http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Thank you for the input @Nico.

Comment: Where should Random be placed?

Comment: I have moved it out of the for loop as you want only one instance of your `Random` or more appropriately a static variable.

Comment: Ohhh yes i see that now. Thank you, i will give that a try. As for my output of all of the game results, that was erroring out at the gameArray[arrayIndex].Result = game; line, which is line 154 of the Game class. I have a feeling i am not referencing the array correctly

Comment: @KevinBorkowski for fun I put together a sample. RPS game. https://gist.github.com/Nico-VanHaaster/647e2f4be3a24b0f81ac196f60d78ea3

Comment: Thanks @Nico. I really appreciate all of the help.